# Normal linear model: distribution of $\xi$ under hypothesis?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

Assume $X$ is normally distributed on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with mean $\xi$ and variance $\sigma^2 I$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

What is our best estimate of $\xi$ given that we know it lies in some subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$? My textbook says that it is the ortogonal projection of $X$ onto that very same subspace, but this is kind of abstract, no?

Also, let us say that we hypothesize that the mean vector is the zero vector. What, then, is the estimate under the hypothesis?

EDIT:

Okay, I think I understood the first question. We have a formula for the ortogonal projection given by $A(A^T A)A^{-1}X$ where $A$ is the design matrix. I used this in an actual calculation where the mean was the same for all marginal random variables, and so with $A = [1,1,1,1 ... 1]^T$, the result actually gives us the sample mean, as one would expect.

The second question still bothers me. What is the projection "under the hypothesis"?

Comment: The "hypothesis" asserts that $\xi$ lies in a particular (precisely and completely specified) subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.